# Input loop number missing loop

Tags: java

Whenever I input x (number of empoyee) as any number it always short in 1 loop when asking  the employee salary. And if i put x as 1 it doesn't ask me.
 Need help how to fix it.

```
class salary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0;
        int y;

        System.out.println("Enter how many employee");
        x = EasyIn.getInt();

        for (int i = 1; i < x; ++i) {
            System.out.println("Enter the salary of employee " + i);
            y = EasyIn.getInt();
            if (y < 20000) {
                System.out.println("This employee Bonus Rate is 7%");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start `i` from `0` then. And print `Enter the salary of employee " + (i+1)`

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your for loop. It should be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
```

or:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
```

<strike>What is EasyIn?</strike>

There might also be an issue with your EasyIn class.

Comment: The last part is a comment, not a part of the answer. Please don't mix the two

Comment: We use Textpad and EasyIn use to record input. Idk why we dont use eclipse so we dont have to use easyin, we have to place easyin.java in every folder that has program in it...

Comment: @OFWGKTA if you are planning to use arrays inside the loop then do modify the loop counter and/or condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
for (int i = 1; i < x; ++i)
```

Think about the terminating condition of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
 // start at 0.
 for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i)
 {
     // add one for display.
     System.out.println("Enter the salary of employee " + (1+i));
     y = EasyIn.getInt();
     if(y < 20000)
     {
       System.out.println("This employee Bonus Rate is 7%");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are starting i from 1 instead of zero so it will always short by 1.
Simply change `int i=1;` to `int i=0;`